# Involve users in designing Stack logos?

Tags: feature-request, design, meta, logo

The stack communities is what makes Stack Exchange unique and great.
Yet it is really disturbing to see the same logo design (blue message box) used for more than one community for a long time (until it's released from beta).

So why not **involve the users** by helping in **logo design**?

There are several notes that will make this a competitive idea among users:

- Make a *design competition* (that any Stack user can enter) once every week.
- Users are asked to design a logo for a community (every week one community that has no logo will be chosen according to it's number of users and popularity)
- There will be several standards and guidelines for users to follow so their design will be accepted (ex: design extension, image dimensions, file size...)
- Users upload their design to a specific server or email it to a specific email given to them.
- After all designs are submitted, users are welcome to *vote* for the designs they think are the best (Every user may have a limited number of votes).
- At the end of the voting period (1 day maybe) the logo with the most votes is chosen to represent the community, and the designer gets *reputation points*, and maybe a *badge*!
- Also all participants who had their logos get more than a certain number of votes could earn some reputation points thanks to their work.

At last, i think that this would make a good deal to Stack users and the Stack Communities themselves and everyone would be definitely glad if it really happened!

Comment: This is the beta icon. When site graduates, it's getting its own unique logo.

Comment: I know that.  Does that make involving users a bad idea?

Comment: No, I didn't downvote. But the logo is probably the easiest part of designing a site, I don't think SE really needs our help. This will be ultra complex mechanism, for little gain.

Comment: It may look like an easy part of designing the website. But the website is already designed. Yet It could be a considerable part of maintenance, and it's the only thing that the user may be helping in.
Maybe with the increasing number of communities, it will be a good solution for later. (Imagine when we reach a state that as soon as a new community is introduced, a new logo competition will begin..) And maybe it will encourage more users to start using SE.

Comment: the website is not "already designed". Take a look at posts like http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design and http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design to see what goes into designing a site. Not just the logo, the vote buttons, the colour scheme, the background image, the accepted answer designation, the badge symbols...there is SO MUCH. Feedback is sought on the site Meta (as you can see from those links) but design work is done by a designer.

Answer (score 8):

I think it's better to have beta sites **consistent**, and to have main sites **branded professionally**, as they are now.

---

Activities like contests to involve the users are great, but they should be about the *actual topic of the site*, not unrelated things like logo design - to build communities of experts, not of dabbling designers.

For example, I see you're active on the Joomla beta site. If you want a community activity to draw in Joomla experts, it'd be better to create a contest that rewards Joomla expertise - not one which excludes non-designers.

I see you're both a designer and a Joomla coder, so a design contest might be fun for you: but wouldn't do much for Joomla developers, site builders, admins etc. Best to choose something more inclusive.

---

After the edit, you mentioned weekly design contests for any SE user. That kinda already exists - [the graphic design site has a design challenge every Thursday](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2732/thursday-weekly-design-challenge). It's very much a just-for-fun thing, and anyone is welcome to join. The designs produced aren't used for anything, because as every pro designer knows, [design contests aren't a good way to get quality designs](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2025/are-logo-design-contests-considered-spec-work-and-what-are-the-pros-and-cons-o).

"Design a logo for a stack site that doesn't have one" would be a fun design challenge, actually, and if you suggest it in the GD.SE chat or meta you'd probably get a positive response, but there should be no expectation that the logos would actually be used, it'd just be a fun exercise.

---

As a regular at [the graphic design site](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com), I'll just add that even the graphic design site didn't have any kind of user contest for the design - and the community was quite happy with that.

There's a lot of truth in the expression "too many cooks spoil the broth", and no-one wants the dreaded "design by committee". If you want professional results, it's best to assign a professional to do it, and don't interfere except for normal [feedback and revision cycles](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/836/updated-march-14-design-for-graphicdesign-se).

---